# SqlDependencyEx: Update notification not being triggered for an update statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldependencyex

We're trying to use [SqlDependencyEx](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener) to track updates made to a database table.

This is how we create an update listener:

```
var listener = new SqlDependencyEx(ConfigUtils.GetConnectionString(),
              ConfigUtils.GetDbName(), "codeTriggers", 
              listenerType: SqlDependencyEx.NotificationTypes.Update);
```

Here is the update statement which we manually trigger in sql management studio:

```
UPDATE codeTriggers
SET type = 'clearListsCache'
WHERE type = 'clearCache'
```

**PROBLEM**

We do not get any notifications.
What are we missing?

When we define our listener as follows (without specifying any type of notification type):

`var listener = new SqlDependencyEx(ConfigUtils.GetConnectionString(), ConfigUtils.GetDbName(), "codeTriggers");`

and we run the same update statement (updating the column to a different value then actual), then we get Insert and Delete notifications.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Isn't it the same as in this issue: https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener/issues/40?

Comment: It sounds a bit similar indeed. We will try specifying 2 listeners: one for Update and one for Insert and see if our Update gets triggered then.

Comment: @Evk Yesterday we tried out the issue mentioned in that link. We were not able to simulate the behavior described there.
And our issue is different. We don't get any Update notifications, only Delete and Insert.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Copy pasted code you provided, updated one column in target table using SSMS, `TableChanged` handler has been called with notification type "Update". So you need to provide more info and maybe minimal example you are able to reproduce that with (console application). I used this version: https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener/blob/master/ServiceBrokerListener/ServiceBrokerListener.Domain/SqlDependencyEx.cs (copy pasted whole file into test project).